# How to use yarpgen random C program generator?

Tags: c, generator, code-generation

I am new here.
Could anyone help me, on how to use yarpgen to generate a random c program.

I tried running the `run_gen.py` script that I saw [in the yarpgen readme](https://github.com/intel/yarpgen/blob/master/README.md).
But, I got a warning and an error like this:

```
Warning: please set YARPGEN_HOME envirnoment variable to point to test generator path, using C:\Users\..\Python\Python36-32\yarpgen-master for now
```

and

```
File C:\Users\..\Python\Python36-32\yarpgen-master\yarpgen wasn't found
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: "enter link description here"? (But I see `envirnoment ` is indeed *sic* in [the source](https://github.com/intel/yarpgen/blob/master/run_gen.py), so that is not a typo of yours.) Also, did you set the `YARPGEN_HOME` envirnoment variable, as was suggested?

Answer (score 1):

The warning very likely points to the source of the problem, run_gen does not know where the other parts of yarpgen are installed.

First, note down the directory you installed/copied yarpgen to.

Then open a command shell. Type this:

```
cd <where run_gen.py is>
set YARPGEN_HOME=<the path you just noted down>
run_gen.py
```

If this works, you can write a batch script, that contains the set `YARPGEN_HOME=...` line and then calls `run_gen.py`. If the directory where run_gen.py is located is not on your PATH environment variable, call run_gen.py with the full absolute path in the batch script:

```
set YARPGEN_HOME=<the path to yarpgen>
python3 <absolute_path_to>\run_gen.py
```

Then you can call your batch script.

You may have to adjust the python3 command depending on the executable Python 3 installed on your machine (it may be just python on Windows).

When I tried this after building with cygwin, I noticed that I had to rename yarpgen.exe to yarpgen to make it work.

Comment: Thanks, I have one more query what should I include in the batch script. I have  saved my batch script it contains. `set HOME_YARPGEN=path/to/dir/of/run_gen.py ``run_gen.py` when I run the batch script, it opened in my pycharm ide and gave me the same `File C:\Users\..\Python\Python36-32\yarpgen-master\yarpgen wasn't found` kindly help @PaulR

Comment: @gavafa: did you run make to build yarpgen? Where is the executable, probably YARPGEN_HOME must point there, if it is not the same directory run_gen.py is in.